# Is there any function to make a auto click event on any position in the screen(UI) - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app. I want to make a click event somewhere on the screen of users phone automatically after loading some content. Is there any function in flutter that automatically clicks or triggers the click event on certain x,y axis of the mobile screen, without making the user explicitly touch the screen.

Edit1: I don't want to bind the click event to some button. I want the click event to happen on some particular x,y axis on the screen when called upon.

Comment: is this in your app, or everywhere in the operating system whilst the app is running in the background?

Comment: @cas Just within my app

Comment: there's no need to simulate a click event, just execute whatever function that click is supposed to call

Comment: @cas that's what I've done for now but my app is very laggy though not because  of it.